VueWrapper error after typescript update to v5.5.2
When I update my project's TypeScript dependency to the version v5.5.2 from 5.4.5 it completely breaks my checks in test.ts files specifically with VueWrapper type, I use vitest.
type error
My usual implementation looks like:
let wrapper: VueWrapper<InstanceType<typeof SomeComponentToTest>>;

//also try
let wrapper: VueWrapper<any>;

//and 
let wrapper: VueWrapper<typeof SomeComponentToTest>;


describe('SomeComponentToTest component tests', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
     //before each test set up
    }
    test('some test to the component' ()=>{
     //...
    })
}


But always get the same error in the wrapper declaration:  Generic type 'VueWrapper<VM, T>' requires 2 type argument(s)
The error seems self-explanatory, but I have no idea how to fix it.
the tests keeps working as usual, the problem is only when i run vue-tsc --noEmit

this problem is related to one error on the src/vue-test-utils.d.ts file:
    declare module '@vue/test-utils' {
      export class VueWrapper {
        findByTestId(testId: string): DOMWrapper[];
  }

when it should be:
declare module '@vue/test-utils' {
  interface VueWrapper {
    findByTestId(testId: string): DOMWrapper[];
  }

that solve the issue
pd: sorry for the bad english
